# Auto-increment based on other column repeats

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro or formula that can do this:

```
Column A Values:

1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
6
6
```

I need Column B to do:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
1
2
```

Because column B has to have an increment number while column A has the same repeated value (for example `1 1 1 2`), when it changes (to 2 or 3 etc.) the counter on column B has to reset and increment itself while A repeats the next value (`1 2 3 1`)

*Thanks*

Comment: Do you have any code to share with which you already tried to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Have a look at bzimor's answer as he solves is in a more general way without a hard value in column B1!

**Original Answer**

You can solve it the following way without VBA:

Put a hard value of 1 in column B1. This is your start value and should be always correct because you start counting with 1.

Then enter the following formula in B2

```
=IF($A2=$A1;$B1+1;1)
```

Just drag the formula down to the other rows of B and you're done

So B3 should look like this

```
=IF($A3=$A2;$B2+1;1)
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use single formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

Put it into cell `B1` and fill down

Comment: Great Solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Here is your desired macros
    Sub jkjainGenerateSerialNumber20161124()
        readcol = Val(InputBox("type ref col#"))
        writecol = Val(InputBox("type dest col#"))
        ts = 0
        Range("A1000000").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        lastrow = ActiveCell.Row

        For n = 2 To lastrow
        prev = Cells(n - 1, readcol)
        curr = Cells(n, readcol)

        If prev <> curr Then
        ts = 1
        End If

        If prev = curr Then
        ts = ts + 1
        End If

        Cells(n, writecol) = ts
        Next
     End Sub
```